# How to avoid the saturation of the current amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I have to calculate current gain of the following circuit and to model it in Spice. I arbitrarily set Is = 0.0002 A:
[image]
Here are the results provided by LTSpice:
 [image]
Also, in order to find an equation for current gain, my first idea was to transform Is and its parallel 5k resistor to a combination of voltage source (Vs = Is*5000 Ohm = 1V) and series 5k resistor. In this case the voltage at inverting input is Vy = Vx = 0.33*Vout, and the output voltage itself can be found according to following equation: (Vs - Vy)/5000 = (Vy - Vout)/20000.
[image]
Strangely, the results provided by LTSpice become quite disturbing when I increase the voltage to 2V (or current to 0.0004 A):
[image]
The same happens when I increase the value of 5k or 2k resistors. As you can see, I had a good luck arbitrarily choosing Is value as 0.0002 A. Otherwise, I could have very hard times.
In general, if I keep all the resistors as they are and don't increase the current above 0.0004 A, then the output voltage can be calculated following these equations:

```
(5k*I1 - 1/3Vout)/5k = (1/3Vout - Vout)/20k;
6R*Is = Vout;
6*5000*0.0002 = 6 V;
```

My question is: how to correctly select voltage/current source and resistor values in order to avoid op-amp saturation?

Comment: How did you get the \$2\:\text{V}\$ for \$V_3\$?

Comment: @jonk , I mistaped. And it works!

Comment: You are good, then!

Comment: @jonk, please, can you take a look once again on my question?

Comment: The opamp in your diagram isn't stable. If the output were to slightly rise, for example, this would increase the voltage at the (+) input node. But this would then cause the opamp to raise its output voltage. Which would increase the (+) input node, still more. It will "hit the rails," in this arrangement. If you hook up the \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ divider node to the (-) input, instead, then this aspect of the problem is fixed.

Comment: If you solve the equations correctly, and arrange the feedback correctly (swap things), I believe you will find that \$V_\text{OUT}=V_\text{IN}\frac{R_2\left(R_3+R_4\right)}{R_2 \,R_4-R_1\,R_3}\$. Note carefully the divisor, though. It can be positive, negative, or zero. There is some danger hidden there.

Comment: Ah, @jonk saw the same. One of use has a wrong sign :)

Comment: @Huisman Yes. The divisor must be positive. If zero, bad things of course. If the divisor is negative, then the fact that the \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ divider is now (after correction) tied to the (+) input means the opamp output will rail since it can't move in the correct direction given which input it is tied to.

Comment: I agree when the divisor is zero or close to zero, the opamp will clip either to the positve or negative rail. But I don't see why it the divisor must be positive, because \$V_\text{cc negative supply} = -100 V\$

Comment: @Huisman I'm not discussing the case shown by the OP's first diagram. I'm discussing the mentally modified one I've been discussing in comments. In my mentally imagined case the R3 and R4 divider node is tied to (-) and the R1 and R2 divider node is tied to (+).

Comment: @Huisman In my imagined case, consider the situation where \$V_3\$ increases upward. This will increase the (+) input. The gain is arranged so that it must be negative-valued (assuming the divisor is negative per the case under consideration.) So this means that the output needs to become more negative. But since the (+) input rose upward slightly, the output will try to reach this "more negative" voltage by itself rising upward. And that's the wrong direction. So it will just rail, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve the circuit, you'll find the reason why it's not stable:

\$V_+\$ and \$V_-\$ being the positive and negative terminal of the opamp

$$ V_+ = V_{out} \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} $$
$$ V_- = (V_{out}-V_3) \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} + V_3 $$
$$ V_{out} = A (V_+ -V_-) $$

$$ V_{out} = A (V_{out} \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} - (V_{out}-V_3) \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - V_3 ) $$

$$ V_{out} = A V_{out} (\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} - \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}) + A V_3 (\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1) $$

$$ \frac{V_{out}}{A} - V_{out} (\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} - \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}) = V_3 (\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1) $$

$$ \lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{V_{out}}{A} - V_{out} (\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} - \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}) = V_3 (\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1) $$

$$ - V_{out} = V_3 \frac{ (\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1) }{ (\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} - \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2})  } $$

$$ - V_{out} = V_3 \frac{ R_2 }{ (\frac{R_4(R_1+R_2)}{R_3+R_4} - R_1 ) } $$

$$ - V_{out} = V_3 \frac{ R_2(R_3+R_4) }{ (R_4(R_1+R_2) - R_1(R_3+R_4) ) } $$

$$ V_{out} = - V_3 \frac{ R_2 R_3 + R_2 R_4 }{ R_4 R_2 - R_1 R_3 } $$

Comment: Where do these equations come from?

Comment: From your 3rd or 4th posted schematic.

Comment: I mean, where does the idea to calculate separately the voltages for op-amp inputs and then to calculate a limit comes from? I use "Electric circuits" of Alexander/Sadiku and had no idea of this method.

Comment: I can't remember. I'll check up my old textbooks and provide a reference. But I might as well have made up the technique myself.